# To where does a pointer point after being deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator

When we use `delete` for a `pointer` (`delete p;`), and don't use `nullptr` for it then, it points to some else location in memory. Can that new location have a valid value so that we can use it in the code?

Comment: The misconception is in the language. You don't actually "delete the pointer"; rather, you "delete the object to which the pointer points". After the deletion, the pointer value is meaningless (but the pointer of course continues existing).

Comment: Agreed. It means that that pointer still points to that memory adress. Nothing changed, the only thing that changed is that the memory at that address (up to the size of the object the pointer was pointing to) Is no longer valid, and marked as invalid/free to be resused memory. Although your value might still be there, if you try to access that you will trigger the OS. Based on the OS is more or less forgiving.

Comment: It still points to the same location, and probably still contains the same data as the memory is not (immediately) cleared. However, the memory is not yours, and the next allocation may or may not use the same location.

Comment: An implementation of delete is allowed to zero out an lvalue operand.

Comment: Answer: it points to undefined behavior.

Comment: An attempt to access at that space would succeed if the space hasn't been repurposed, or would yield segfault/Access violation if it has; which is undefined.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What do you mean by _the pointer value_ please? I tested a small program and used a pointer there. [Before deletion](http://www.4shared.com/download/pwOuqMLjce/1__2_.PNG?sbsr=cd96aa7714b552980dd84070c9d0a9bc967&lgfp=3000) it points to an object (containing the value 6) And [after deletion](http://www.4shared.com/download/jVScvgXkce/2__3_.PNG?sbsr=80ae88182032093ddedf12751dbc3aac967&lgfp=3000) the object will be deleted and also the pointer's address is changed!

Comment: @franky: No, the pointer's address is not changed, nor is the pointer's value changed. The pointer's value has just become unusable. It's still the same value as before, but you must not dereference it any longer (nor must you perform relational comparisons on it). You're either doing something wrong or misinterpreting something. "Value" means what it always means in C++, e.g. for `int n = 10;`, the value of `n` is `10`.

Comment: My misunderstanding is about pointers. So for clearing up the issue, what is _the pointer value_ in the code _before deletion_ in my previous post please?

Answer (score 3):

Whether a pointer points to the same location or a different location after it has been `delete`d is not specified by the language. An implementation is free to do whatever they wish to do with the value of that pointer.

> Can that new location have a valid value so that we can use it in the code?

That's up to your code. The compiler is not required to do so.

Comment: Whatever I tested it on my MS VS compiler, it pointed to a very different location in memory after being `delete`d. But how can it be up to the code? Would you offer a code that we can `delete` a pointer, then, use the value of the new location to which it points now? (To me it's not allowed!) :-)

Comment: @franky, VS does different things in debug builds vs in release builds. I wouldn't count on what they do beyond what the language guarantees. You can use `delete ptr; ptr = nullptr;` in your code. The hard part of what you are asking is: do you know, in your program, what will be a valid pointer value? If you do, you can set a pointer to that value.

Comment: Thanks for you helps. The value inside the pointer which is an hexadecimal address (on my Windows machine) points to some location. That location is some different one compared to the one the pointer pointed before being deleted. That new location may have some valid value. I say a value is valid and we can use it for the code, if we can extract it using (for example) the pointer, `*p`.

Comment: @franky, The address that pointer points to after it is `delete`d is not to be used as `*p`. That will lead to undefined behavior.